# Embedd fonts in a TextArea in Flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea, flex4, tlf

I'm trying to embedd fonts to use with a TextArea that I have extended using the code below, but it doesn't work. I have used this code before with a TextFlow object and then set the containers with the flowComposer, but I can't get it to work with the TextArea.

When using the code below and set the text with setText, all I get is Times New Roman font. (Everything else is working fine)

```
<s:TextArea ... >

...

<fx:Style>

    @font-face {
     src: url("./fonts/arial.ttf");
     font-family: ArialEmbedded;
   }

</fx:Style>

...

public function setText(text:String):void 
{
  var format:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
  format.color = 0x000000;
  format.renderingMode = RenderingMode.CFF;
  format.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;

  var config:Configuration = new Configuration();
  config.textFlowInitialFormat = format;     

  textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT, config);
  textFlow.interactionManager = new EditManager(); 
}  

</s:TextArea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same type of behavior with a TextArea and TextInput.  The spark components will not render embedded fonts.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should set embedAsCFF to true.
From the spark component, text-related components are re-based on
Flash Player 10's text rendering engine(FTE).

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/15/embedding-fonts-in-flex-gumbo/